# How can I get month name from month number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, time

I can get the next month's month number and year with:

```
(Time.now + 1.month).month
# => 10
(Time.now + 1.month).year
# => 2015
```

How can I get `"October"` from `10`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use format string.

```
(Time.now + 1.month).strftime("%B")
# => "October"
```

Comment: it works, but ignores the locale

Comment: @ArupRakshit yep, that's true, but i thought it might be still useful to mention.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the actual question that was asked.  The asker's input is a number, not a date.

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier It does. The OP asked generally how to get the month name. `10` was an example in this case. The `10` in question because the question was asked in `Sep` month, and added 1 month to date, which is `Oct`. The example in the question is not really the direct question.

Answer (score 69):

You can use Date's monthnames constant

```
Date::MONTHNAMES[10] => "October"
```

Comment: In my case I needed to get the month name "lets say September" from an integer, that integer is all I have and I have no control over changing it, so I used this `<%= Date::MONTHNAMES[month] %>` worked like a charm

Comment: Thank you. Your answer saved me a great deal of time.

Answer (score 41):

Ruby Date class provides a constant array of month names. You can pass month number as index and will get month name

```
Date::MONTHNAMES[10]
# November
```

To get abbreviated month name

```
Date::ABBR_MONTHNAMES[10]
# Nov
```

Or you can also get month name from date using strftime %B formater like

```
Date.today.strftime(%B)
# September
```

similarly

```
(Time.now + 1.month).strftime('%B')
# November
```

If your application is multi-lingual or using language other then english, you can get localized month name using I18n

```
I18n.l(Time.now, format: "%B")
```

Comment: Sums up the three options.  I prefer the individual answers which are voted up and down to show their relative merits.

Comment: It seems like in more recent versions, Date::MONTHNAMES has month names mapped to the month number in the calendar, so `Date::MONTHNAMES[10] == "October"` now.

Answer (score 18):

I think it should be done with the help of I18n module, since `strftime` ignores the locale:

```
(Time.now + 1.month).strftime("%B") # => 'October'

I18n.l(Time.now + 1.month, format: "%B") # => 'Oktober'
```